# Wrong default system font in LibreOffice GUI on Max OS X

Tags: macos, libreoffice

I've been looking for an answer to my issue everywhere but with no results so far. I am using LibreOffice 5.1.4.2 and noticed that the default font for headers is just not the correct one. Here is a screenshot so you can see what I mean:

[image: Wrong default font for header]

I don't know which font it should be, I've read about Helvetica Neue or maybe the default system font on El Capitan, San Francisco. I don't even know which font is used in the screenshot above (it's too small).

Here is a topic about the same issue but no working answer: [libre office gui has wrong font bug](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/66890/libre-office-gui-has-wrong-font-bug/).

I've tried deleting and re-installing the software, deleting the user profile and the cache and mapping Helvetica Neue to another font in LibreOffice.

I don't really know what to try know... If someone could answer these questions that would really help me:

- How can I find out which font should be used by default by LibreOffice on Mac El Capitan?
- How can I find out which font is currently used?
- How can I solve my issue?

Thanks!

Comment: You might have better luck on a user-oriented site, since this is off-topic for programming.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but I had the same problem and found the solution here: https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/131310/libreoffice-54-font-gui-problem-just-rectangles-macos/

It is a MacOS specific problem with font-mapping.

Long story short:

1. Open Applications / Font Book.app
2. File -> Restore Standard Fonts
3. All non-system/default fonts will be removed and put into ~/Library/Fonts (Removed)
4. Close and reopen LibreOffice; it should work now
5. Optionally: reinstall the fonts from the removed folder and check if it still works; if not, rinse and repeat until you have identified the culprit font.

In my case, I had another version of Helvetica Neue installed.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've reinstalled macOs since that problem and didn't have the issue anymore so your answer makes sense. +1 for taking the time to come back here and share your knowledge :)